# Calling the plotting method of the encapsulated class cannot output the result

Tags: python-3.x, class

I tried to transform the `ThymeBoost` test code ([basic examples](https://github.com/tblume1992/ThymeBoost/tree/main)) into a Python class called `TimeSeriesPredictor`, as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from ThymeBoost import ThymeBoost as tb

class TimeSeriesPredictor:
    def __init__(self, y, seasonal_period=25, cost_penalty=.001, n_split_proposals=25, verbose=1):
        self.y = y
        self.seasonal_period = seasonal_period
        self.cost_penalty = cost_penalty
        self.n_split_proposals = n_split_proposals
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.boosted_model = None
        self.output = None
        self.predicted_output = None

    def fit_model(self, trend_estimator='linear', seasonal_estimator='fourier', split_cost='mse', global_cost='maicc', fit_type='local'):
        self.boosted_model = tb.ThymeBoost(
                            approximate_splits=True,
                            n_split_proposals=self.n_split_proposals,
                            verbose=self.verbose,
                            cost_penalty=self.cost_penalty,
                            )

        self.output = self.boosted_model.fit(self.y,
                           trend_estimator=trend_estimator,
                           seasonal_estimator=seasonal_estimator,
                           seasonal_period=self.seasonal_period,
                           split_cost=split_cost,
                           global_cost=global_cost,
                           fit_type=fit_type)

    def predict(self, n_steps):
        self.predicted_output = self.boosted_model.predict(self.output, n_steps)

    def plot_results(self):
        plt.plot(self.y)
        plt.plot(self.predicted_output)
        plt.show()

    def plot_components(self):
        self.boosted_model.plot_components(self.output)
        plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #Here we will just create a random series with seasonality and a slight trend
    seasonality = ((np.cos(np.arange(1, 101))*10 + 50))
    np.random.seed(100)
    true = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
    noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
    y = true + noise + seasonality
    y = np.append(y, true + noise + seasonality)

    predictor = TimeSeriesPredictor(y)
    predictor.fit_model()
    predictor.predict(100)
    predictor.plot_results()
    predictor.plot_components()
```

But it can only print out the following content, but cannot output figures. How can I improve this code to solve this issue? Thanks.

Output:

```
********** Round 1 **********
Using Split: None
Fitting initial trend globally with trend model:
median()
seasonal model:
fourier(10, False)
cost: 178.29215636637585
********** Round 2 **********
Using Split: 196
Fitting local with trend model:
linear((1, None))
seasonal model:
fourier(10, False)
cost: 170.15461510349348
********** Round 3 **********
Using Split: 158
Fitting local with trend model:
linear((1, None))
seasonal model:
fourier(10, False)
cost: 168.69710853512558
********** Round 4 **********
Using Split: 58
Fitting local with trend model:
linear((1, None))
seasonal model:
fourier(10, False)
cost: 168.3484150897301
==============================
Boosting Terminated 
Using round 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I re-ran the program today and produced the following results:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dev of the package here thanks for checking it out, looks like you got it to work! Just remember that the plotting methods in thymeboost call plt.show() in them rather than returning the plot object. Also the output dataframe contains all the components of the forecast! Let me know if you have any other issues,!